# How to fix ClientRead after huge insert in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I'm using postgresql 15.1. I wrote a stored procedure that reads all data of previous month from a partitioned table `data_202306`, then do some update from another data table and finally insert it into a new partition `data_202307`.
The data volume is around 20 million rows per partition.
To have it faster, I have already use CTE statements that first select those result using `with` statement and finally insert them.

When I execute the function, the function just won't stop unless using `pg_terminate_backend` to have a force stop.

I've checked `pg_stat_activity` command and found my function stops at idle with wait event of `ClientRead` after executing for ~10 mins.
What surprised me is after terminated the session using `pg_terminate_backend` and check the table, new data would show in `data_202307`. So I think `ClientRead` wait event means PGSQL has already done the insert but somehow it was stuck after that.

Comment: Consider utilizing temporary tables, as they are generally faster than CTE (Common Table Expressions) statements. Additionally, if indexing is not currently implemented, it will advisable to apply indexing to the tables for enhanced performance.

Comment: Consider checking for `pg_locks` or utilize `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` to gain insights into how your query is executing. If these methods do not provide clarity, examine the `pg_log` directory for further investigation.

Comment: If the session has `state = 'idle'` in `pg_stat_activity`, the transaction and all its statements are done and control has returned to the client. The problem must be on the client side or in the network.

Comment: Sounds like the procedure has finished, and the client has failed to notice.  If you are using a CLI like psql, just go to that terminal and hit return or space, and see if the prompt suddenly appears.  If not using CLI, then you should tell us what you are doing to execute this procedure.

Comment: @jjanes Yea I agree with you about client fail to notice. I've tried both executing it on dbeaver 6.0.2 and through python SQLAlchemy package by simply executing `select function(202307)` to execute it and that issue occurs. Hope it provides information you need.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Thanks for your analysis. Probably that's a network issue. The function is mainly inserting data into a new table and I don't need to return it's data to client. Therefore I don't think network issue comes from huge data transfer. I think it might be some timeout mechanism. Do you have any suggestions on how to fix it? I was hoping to get some tips on configuration settings that could fix it.

Comment: @UtkarshDubey As you suggested I've tried `pg_locks`. I execute my function until it has a `ClientRead` again. After that I execute `select * from pg_locks where "granted" = false` and no row as found. I think it menas nothing was stucked by lock.

Comment: @UtkarshDubey And I tried `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` just now. As the function won't end, I can't retrieve the result of explanation from pgsql.

Comment: @jjjjlau, Have you considered substituting Common Table Expressions (CTEs) with temporary tables. Additionally, have you examined the contents of the `pg_log` directory?

Comment: @UtkarshDubey I'm trying on it temporary tables. Actually my first code insert data into `data_202307` first and do update on it. Yet it was too slow then I switch to CTE. As for `pg_log`, I don't have access on that. Will try ask.

Comment: I have no suggestions, since I don't know what client you are using and how your network is set up.

Comment: @UtkarshDubey I've tried change CTE into temporary table. Unfortunately that didn't fix my issue and that `ClientRead` status occured after longer execution (from ~10min to ~20min). My function needs to have a update on each row so I think that update will have significantly slow that function.